# Raise x to power of y in ptx nvidia cuda (assembly)

Tags: cuda, nvidia, ptx

I want to raise x to the power of y in ptx.

Nvidia has a function **ex2** which calculates 2^x and **lg2** which calculates log2x but there's no function for calculating x^y.

Is there more clever and simpler solution that multiplying value in loop? How code from .cu file is converted to .ptx when it has `pow(x, y)`?

Maybe there's clever solution with using **ex2** and **lg2** to calculate **x^y**?

**Solution**:

As @talonmies mentioned:

if `z = x^y`, then `log2(z) = y * log2(x)`
so `x^y = 2^(y*log2(x))`

Comment: if `z = x^y`, then `log2(z) = y * log2(x)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how nvcc does it.

```
__global__
void exp(float x, float y, float* z) {
    *z = powf(x,y);
}
```

`nvcc --ptx --use_fast_math exp.cu`

exp.ptx

```
.visible .entry _Z3expffPf(
    .param .f32 _Z3expffPf_param_0,
    .param .f32 _Z3expffPf_param_1,
    .param .u64 _Z3expffPf_param_2
)
{
    .reg .f32   %f<6>;
    .reg .b64   %rd<3>;


    ld.param.f32    %f1, [_Z3expffPf_param_0];
    ld.param.f32    %f2, [_Z3expffPf_param_1];
    ld.param.u64    %rd1, [_Z3expffPf_param_2];
    cvta.to.global.u64  %rd2, %rd1;
    lg2.approx.ftz.f32  %f3, %f1;
    mul.ftz.f32     %f4, %f3, %f2;
    ex2.approx.ftz.f32  %f5, %f4;
    st.global.f32   [%rd2], %f5;
    ret;
}
```

It's worth comparing this ptx to what you get without `--use_fast_math`.